# Facebook Login blocked on iOS app due to "non-iOS approved payment method allowed" reason

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, payment, facebook-ios-sdk

Facebook Login (or Connect) has been blocked by Facebook on our app (Ubudu for iOS, available on French app store). The reason stated by FB support is below, but I dont understand it since the app is entirely free, and the only transaction in the process is linking to mobile web pages where physical products and services are sold.

Anybody has a solution how to get over it?

Message from FB support:
"Your app [XXX] allows/links to a purchase flow through the 'Facebook for iOS' app. This is a non-iOS approved payment method and is in violation of the following policy:

Mobile Web Apps that are running within a Facebook iOS app may only use iOS approved payment methods. These apps must not reference, use, or otherwise encourage use of Facebook Credits and other non-iOS approved payment methods.

Hence your mobile web app will be blocked on 'Facebook for iOS' (which means you will not appear in search, bookmarks, requests and newsfeed) on 'Facebook for iOS' due to violation of the following policy :

You may reference to payment options in your canvas (desktop) application and on m.facebook.com just not your mobile application within 'Facebook for iOS'.
(...)"

/Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's what Facebook means.  They never actually said *you* were selling anything, they said that you were providing the means to circumvent Apple's 30% cut on in-app goods with the links you provide to physical merchandise.  If these links are to retailers, carefully explain your position to FB in an appeal, however, if you yourself are selling these things, the use of iApp money for physical goods is strictly prohibited.

Comment: Thanks CodaFi, that's exactly what i did. But it seems FB support takes its time to reply back...

Comment: Yep.  FB is generally awful about... Everything mobile.  Give it some time, soothe clients' nerves if necessary.